# VScode: Is there a way to hide symlink results from Goto file.. (quick file open) in VScode? And search in general?

Tags: search, visual-studio-code, symlink

When one searches or uses the Goto file (Quick open) command (cmd+P), the search automatically includes everything from symlink folders. This makes the quick open literary useless if there is a significant symlink folder.

Compare with Atom or Sublime, they only display the 'real' files in their quick opens.

[image]

Is there a way to exclude the symlinks? 
Or is this a feature request?

PS:

In project search, one can forcefully exclude paths, so I exclude the big symlink folders, but it's manual, not persistent, and it still does not affect ctrl+P.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a setting that will disable search from following symlinks.  Disable:

> Search: Follow Symlinks

Comment: Now, if only we could use `files.exclude` and `search.exclude` with symlinks! As it stands you can't exclude symlinks or their subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to know if anyone has a better solution to this. I use my terminal to open VSCode so my solution was to use a bash function to open vscode with the realpath of the directory like this:

```sh
function vscr() {
    python -c "import os,sys; target=os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(sys.argv[1])); os.execv('/usr/local/bin/code', ['', target])" "$1"
}
```

so effectively `vscr <symlink>` expands to `code <realpath>`